# In ASP.NET MVC, how does a controller know which view to call?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, view, controller

This may sound like a dumb question, I'm a fairly experienced programmer but I'm brand new to .NET and MVC.

In a class I was taking, we have a controller class (Homecontroller.cs) I understand that calling Return View() in the ActionResult Index() method will cause .NET to look for a "Home" view with the file Index.cshtml. However, in this example, we have return View(cars) where car is an instance of type Car. So the code does go back to Views/Home/index.html even though there is no "cars" view. But that class is a model of type Car. So if you have a type of object returned in "return View", does ASP.NET search the .chstml files looking for that model type? Or is it still just looking for Home/Index.html because return View is being called from the index method. In brief, how does ASP.NET know, in the code below, to go to Views/Home/Index.cshtml? I'll paste the relevant code below:

Controllers/HomeController.cs:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var cars = HelloMVC.Models.HelloModel.GetCars();

        return View(cars);
    }
}
```

Views/Home/Index.cshtml:

```
@model List<HelloMVC.Models.HelloModel.Car>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@foreach (var car in Model)
{
    <p>@car.ID - @car.Make - @car.Model</p>
}
```

Comment: `return View()`  looks for a view with the same name as the `ActionResult`  to specify a different .cshtml, use `return View("ViewName", model)`  see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/asp-net-mvc-views-overview-cs

Comment: naming conventions

Comment: You could specify a specific view

Answer (score 3):

Locations of search:

```
~/Views/{ControllerName}/{ActionName}.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/{ActionName}.cshtml
```

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET MVC uses a process called "view discovery" to match views with controller actions as described here:

https://asp.mvc-tutorial.com/views/view-discovery-connecting-controller-view/

If you don't pass in a specific view name to look for, it'll look for a view that matches the name of your controller action. So in this case, it will look for Index.cshtml.

One variation of the View() method takes a single object (the model) as a parameter. In your example, the "cars" variable is passed in as the model.

The View() method is documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.view?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2